# Makefile: Can't link .so with .so, undefined symbol during runtime

Tags: c++, ubuntu, makefile, g++

I'm trying to link a .so file with a .so file with no luck in my makefile g++/c++.

Basically I have a bunch of objects I want to use as a library, then I have a shared object I want to link against said library.  I try to load the shared object during runtime and I get an undefined symbol error.

Ex:

```
MyLibraryObjects=LibObject1.o \
LibObject2.o \
LibObject3.o

MyInterfaceObjects=InterfaceObject1.o \
InterfaceObject2.o

CXXFLAGS=-fPIC -shared -I$(MyIncludeDir)

MyLibrary: $(MyLibraryObjects)
    g++ -fPIC -shared -o MyLibrary.so $(MyLibraryObjects) -ldl

MyInterface: $(MyInterfaceObjects)
    g++ -fPIC -shared -o MyInterface.so MyLibrary.so $(MyInterfaceObjects) -ldl
```

Then during runtime I load the MyInterface.so and it doesn't recognize LibObject1 constructor.

I can get it working if I do this:

```
MyInterface: $(MyInterfaceObjects)
        g++ -fPIC -shared -o MyInterface.so $(MyInterfaceObjects) $(MyInterfaceObjects) -ldl
```

But that re-links all the library objects.  I would rather link directly against one .so library object.  So not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0):

My .so file was in the wrong order, I moved it to the end and it worked.